# Read tcl script variables in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, tcl

I would like to include(source) a tcl file in shell script to access the variables of the tcl file in Redhat unix.

I tried the following:

```
source /home/alphagroups/workspace/myTest.tcl
```

However, it threw a syntax error while reading that file apparently because the compiler consider the sourced tcl file also as shell script. Could someone please help me out on this?

Comment: A, sh shell doesn't speak TCL, and a TCL interpreter doesn't speak shell. (No compilers involved here.) What you're trying to do will not work.

Comment: Mat is right, but there are ways to work around this.  What is your script aiming to do with those variable values?

Comment: This definitely smells like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Back up a bit, tell us more about the wider context of the problem and what you are trying to achieve overall. It might be that there are much better approaches that don't involve doing this one particular crazy thing.